# Are these two statements(theorems) equivalent?

Tags: logic, definition, coding-theory

I am given this theorem:

> Let $H$ be a check matrix for a linear code $C$. Then $C$ has minimum
>   distance $d$ iff. there exists a set of $d$, but no set of $d-1$, linearly dependent columns
>   in $H$.

Is the following rephrasing accurate (identical and equivalent in meaning to the above)?

> Let $H$ be a check matrix for a linear code $C$. Then the minimum distance
>   of $C$ is $d \in \mathbb N$ such that there exists a set of $d$, but no set of $d-1$, linearly dependent columns in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The only thing that it possibly differs in is that it includes the assertion that every linear code *has* a minimum distance. If $H$ is a finite matrix, this nuance makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Oh yes, good observation. Well in my text, linear codes are defined over finite fields only, so I guess the two statements above are indeed equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan Is a matrix over a finite field the same as the finite matrix that Lord_Farin is referring to?